# How to Convert .NET DateTime to JSON?

Tags: ios, getjson

createdBy: "f201b814-34c2-4948-9ab2-36a2293d7098"
eventID: 5
forumDescription: "Android Forum 01 Description"
forumID: 1
forumStatus: 3
forumTitle: "Android Forum 01"
lastModifiedDateTime: "/Date(1413427128000+0530)/"
version: 3

### }

1:  {
createdBy: "f201b814-34c2-4948-9ab2-36a2293d7098"
eventID: 5
forumDescription: "Android sdasdasd 02"
forumID: 2
forumStatus: 3
forumTitle: "Android Forum 02"
lastModifiedDateTime: "/Date(1413427135000+0530)/"
version: 3

Comment: JSON doesn't have a date format. Please specify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create Unix timestamp and then use that. Unix timestamp is count of millisecond from 1/1/1970.

For creating timestamp in C# use this:

```
public string ToUnixEpoch(DateTime dateTime)
{
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime d2 = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#");
}
```

For more info [see this](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/net-datetime-to-json-unix-javascript-datetime/). Hope this helps... :)